# DirectoryServices.AccountManagement User Profile Profile Path

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add the User Profile Profile Path information within Active Directory using VB.NET `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` but don't seem to be able to do it. I can add all other fields I need including Logon Script which is in the same tab as Profile Path.

I've been looking at [UserPrincipal at MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) but I can't see anything that relates to Profile Path.

Relevant code:

```
    Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "sometext", "OU=Domain Objects,DC=sometext,DC=local")

    Dim user As New UserPrincipal(ctx, "NewUser", "pass@1w0rd01", True)

    user.GivenName = "GivenName"
    user.Surname = "Surname"
    user.HomeDirectory = "\\MyHomeDirectory\"
    user.HomeDrive = "Z:"

    user.ExpirePasswordNow()

    user.Save()
```